# Update AppBar Title with only re-rending the AppBar

Tags: reactjs

**Objective**

My goal is to have an AppBar at the top of the page that has a title in it. Then in the "Main" area of my screen I will have a route that renders a different component depending on the url. These are the components that need to update the page title that is being rendered in the AppBar. I only want the AppBar to re-render and nothing else, because it's the only thing that will have actual data change in.

Originally I was using `useState()` and just prop drilling the `[pageTitle, setPageTitle]` down to the components. From what I've read, you should avoid prop drilling if possible.

So I've tried leveraging `useContext()` but everything in the tree still re-renders.

**Caveats**

I would like to keep the layout of the HTML like I currently have it if possible. I'm not sure if that affects anything.

**How I Tested For Re-rendering**

I have console.log() statements per component. I got rid of strict mode in order to make sure the components are rendering only once. I tested this prior to leveraging `useContext` and the statements only print out once.

Now when I click on a navigation link you will notice it prints out a `console.log()` for all of the `components` that `<PageTitleContext.Provider>` is wrapping.

I only want the `<AppBar>` to re-render and nothing else, because this is the only `component` that is displaying the `pageTitle`.

**Sandbox Code**

https://codesandbox.io/s/appbar-page-title-update-m5y9el?file=/src/pages/Dashboard.jsx

Comment: It looks like everything working fine. Can you explain what you mean by `everything in the tree still re-renders` like when its happening and how you are saying that ?

Comment: @Arjun I have updated the post with the information